# Go to Definition F12 en VSCODE no funciona con archivos js o css en la carpeta wwwroot

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vscode, cshtml, core

Tengo una aplicacion Asp.net Core tipica con la carpeta wwwroot conteniendo varios archivos js y css.
Cuando trabajo con las vistas, las funciones que creo en javascript en esos archivos no son accesibles con F12 ni con intellisense para mostrar parametros desde los archivos cshtml.
Pero sí en caso de colocar dichas funciones en bloques  dentro de la vista cshtml.
Hay forma de configurar VSCode para disponer de esa facilidad.
Gracias.

Ej:
En la carpeta wwwroot el archivo main.js contiene esa función:

```
function haceralgo(i) {
  ......
}
```

En la vista de la carpeta pages Index.cshtml en los bloques script llamo a dicha funcion:

```
<script>
   haceralgo(1);
</script>
```

Pero si coloco el cursor encima y presiona F12 no lo reconoce.

Comment: vs code es un editor de texto.. si no encontras un plugin que haga eso, no va a funcionar...

Comment: Gracias, en Visual Studio 2022 tampoco funciona.

Comment: he notado que si funciona, siempre y cuando tengas abierto el Js donde está la función que quieres buscar

Comment: Lo acabo de probar y sí, funciona, lastima que no en vscode. gracias.